# jQuery form submit opens a new backround tab what I don't want

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form with 2 submit buttons - save changes and save & continue editing.
Now I've set up a submit with jQuery on CTRL+S for the Save&Continue button like this:

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
    if (!(event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#saveContinue").click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

The problem with this is, that it opens up a new background tab on Opera.
The form in shortened version is like this:

```
<form id="modifyPage" action="index.php" name="modifyPage" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="saveContinue" id="saveContinue" value="Save & Continue" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save Changes" />
</form>
```

Comment: No part of your code suggests it would. Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: a what? Sorry don't understand.

Comment: yes, that makes sense...:) here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/B9cDT/

Comment: when you edit the textarea and hit CTRL+S it opens up a new tab. At least in Opera. Other browsers I dont care. I think it does not even work on others.

Comment: If Opera won't let you override short cuts, then there is probably not much you can do about it. Actually it's probably a good idea for browser developers to stop web developers from hijacking short cuts, so that the users don't get surprised if they suddenly stop working or do something else. Keep in mind, the web isn't a desktop app.  If you "need" this to work then a web app was probably the wrong choice as a platform. You could look into the the `accesskey` property ( http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.2 ), but usage differs strongly between browsers.

Comment: this function is not necessary, I'm just addict to CTRL+S, hit that almost after every line, maybe even word..., so it annoys me when accidentally hit it, and the opera save window appears. Now this code works, the form is submitted, even saves to the DB, it just opens a bg tab with the same content... and that is weird.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `target` attribute or some other JS that attempts to post the form to a new window?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. There is codemirror running for the textarea, but if I turn it completely of (delete from code) it does the same.

Comment: @KristianIvan Sorry, I'm out if ideas.